# Why can't I collect a Vec<&str> from an iterator of references to a struct with String?

Tags: rust

I'm currently learning rust, and I would like to collect a reference of strings (&strs) from a vector of items owning a String.

```rust
struct Channel {
    cid: usize,
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    let channels: Vec<Channel> = vec![Channel {
        cid: 1,
        name: "Hello".to_string(),
    }];
    let names: Vec<&str> = channels.iter().map(|x| &x.name).collect();
}
```

This code does not compile, giving this error:

```
[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<&str>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&String`
    --> src/main.rs:11:61
     |
11   |     let names: Vec<&str> = channels.iter().map(|x| &x.name).collect();
     |                                                             ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<&str>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&String>`
     |
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<&String>` is not implemented for `Vec<&str>`
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<&str>` is implemented for `Vec<&str>`
     = help: for that trait implementation, expected `str`, found `String`
note: the method call chain might not have had the expected associated types
    --> src/main.rs:11:44
     |
7    |       let channels: Vec<Channel> = vec![Channel {
     |  __________________________________-
8    | |         cid: 1,
9    | |         name: "Hello".to_string(),
10   | |     }];
     | |______- this expression has type `Vec<Channel>`
11   |       let names: Vec<&str> = channels.iter().map(|x| &x.name).collect();
     |                                       ------ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Iterator::Item` changed to `&String` here
     |                                       |
     |                                       `Iterator::Item` is `&Channel` here
note: required by a bound in `collect`
    --> /playground/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:2050:19
     |
2050 |     fn collect<B: FromIterator<Self::Item>>(self) -> B
     |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Iterator::collect`
```

I *can* get it to work by calling as_str() to extract the string slice:

`let names: Vec<&str> = channels.iter().map(|x| x.name.as_str()).collect();`

However, I would like to understand *why* this is required. From my understanding, due to deref coercion, a `&String` can be converted to a `&str`. Why do I have to explicitly use `as_str()`? Additionally, performance-wise, is taking `as_str()` the same as taking a reference to an item?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deref coercion *usually* works as you expect, however it depends on the tricky details of type inference. In particular, in this case, the compiler concludes the the closure returns `&String`, and when it realizes we need `&str` it's already too late (after the `collect()`) and it doesn't go back in time to fix it.

There are multiple ways to hint the compiler other than `as_str()`:

```rust
// Notice the `as _`.
let names: Vec<&str> = channels.iter().map(|x| &x.name as _).collect();
```

```rust
let names: Vec<&str> = channels.iter().map(|x| -> &str { &x.name }).collect();
```

```rust
let names: Vec<&str> = channels.iter().map(|x| &*x.name).collect();
```

> Additionally, performance-wise, is taking `as_str()` the same as taking a reference to an item?

Yes. It just does explicitly what the compiler usually does implicitly, but the work needs to be done either way.

Comment: How does `as _` work? Can you `as`-cast `T` to `U` whenever `T` derefs to a `U`?

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes. `as` can perform any coercion, including deref coercion.